# Weird Drupal Error (The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have Drupal 7 with multiple taxonomies and recently for only one (the largest one) when I go to the following taxonomy page:

www.site.com/taxonomy/term/216746

all is fine.

Then when I click edit:

www.site.com/taxonomy/term/216746/edit

My screen goes blank and I see in the console that I get this error:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared.  The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range.  The character encoding of the page must to be
>   declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

This does not happen with any other taxonomy term and suggestions would be great. Also, I looked in the database and I notice any differences between the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on errors in the settings.php with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and I found it was a memory issue.

I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');` to the settings.php file, and all works.

Comment: where are the errors logged for drupal? thank you

Comment: It's under Reports > Recent Log messages or yoursite.com/admin/reports/dblog. In my case the error was printed right to the screen, that's why I turned on display errors.